# Update all documents of Elastic Search using existing column value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field "published_date" in elastic search and there I have full date like **yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss**.

I want to create 3 more columns for **year**, **month** and **date** where I have to use the existing **published_date** to update new 3 columns.

Is there any inbuilt api to do this kind of work in e.s.? I am using elasticsearch 5.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [update-by-query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) in order to do this. It would simply boil down to running something like this:

```
POST your_index/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.year = ctx._source.published_date.date.getYear(); ctx._source.month = ctx._source.published_date.date.getMonthOfYear(); ctx._source.day = ctx._source.published_date.date.getDayOfYear(); ",
    "lang": "groovy"
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Also note that you need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-security.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in order for this to work.

Comment: I am getting this error
error evaluating ctx._source.year = ctx._source.created_date.date.getYear(); ctx._source.month = ctx._source.created_date.date.getMonthOfYear(); ctx._source.day = ctx._source.created_date.date.getDayOfYear();
---
No such property: date for class: java.lang.String\nPossible solutions: bytes

Comment: Then it means that your `published_date` field is not of `date` type but simply a string. How does your mapping look like `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index`?

Comment: value :::: "created_date": "2016-12-04T02:13:53.707Z",
----------
mapping::: "created_date": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "dateOptionalTime"
          }
-------
actual column name is "created_date"

Comment: Is that the mapping you got directly from ES, or the one you think you have created?

Comment: I created manually and I am checking using GET  index_name/_mapping