# Get date value in update query elasticsearch painless

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I'm trying to get millis value of two dates and subtract them to another.
When I used `ctx._sourse.begin_time.toInstant().toEpochMilli()` like `doc['begin_time'].value.toInstant().toEpochMilli()` it gives me runtime error.
And `ctx._source.begin_time.date.getYear()` (like this [Update all documents of Elastic Search using existing column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867756/update-all-documents-of-elastic-search-using-existing-column-value)) give me runtime error with message

```
  "ctx._source.work_time = ctx._source.begin_time.date.getYear()",
  "                                              ^---- HERE"
```

What type I get with `ctx._source` if this code works correctly `doc['begin_time'].value.toInstant().toEpochMilli()`.
I can't find in documentation of painless how to get values correctly. begin_time is date 100%.

So, how can I write a script to get the difference between two dates and write it to another integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look closely, the script language from the linked question is in `groovy` but it's not supported anymore. What we use nowadays (2021) is called `painless`.

The main point here is that the `ctx._source` attributes are the original JSON -- meaning the dates will be strings or integers (depending on the format) and not `java.util.Date` or any other data type that you could call `.getDate()` on. This means we'll have to parse the value first.

So, assuming your `begin_time` is of the format `yyyy/MM/dd`, you can do the following:

```json
POST myindex/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script": {
    "source": """
      DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
      LocalDate begin_date = LocalDate.parse(ctx._source.begin_time, dtf);
      
      ctx._source.work_time = begin_date.getYear()
    """
  }
}
```

BTW the `_update_by_query` script context (what's accessible and what's not) is [documented here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-update-by-query-context.html) and working with datetime in painless is nicely [documented here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-datetime.html#painless-datetime).

Comment: Thank you! Now I clearly understand why in documentation elastic shows me java code.

Comment: Nice -- I'm glad it's clearer now. Hey, I'm writing a handbook full of insights like this. You can [let me know](https://jozefsorocin.typeform.com/to/XeQRxdwV) what parts of ES you'd like to understand better.

Comment: Saved me some time, thank you!